# Integrating without complex analysis

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

How can I evaluate this integral (without complex analysis)?

$$\int_{-\infty}^\infty\sinh [x(1-b)] \exp(iax) dx\qquad a, b\in \mathbb R$$

Thanks.

Comment: The way you have written this, it looks like $\sinh[a(1-b)]$ is just a constant which you can take outside of the integral. In this case the integral $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty} \exp(iax) dx$ does not converge. Maybe you meant to write something else.

Comment: Did you intend to have an $x$ somewhere in the $\sinh$? Yeah, what Aleks said ;-)

Comment: @AleksVlasev: Thanks, very well spotted! It's late and I'm losing it, anyway, I have edited it now.

Comment: @robjohn: You are very right! :-)

Comment: $\sinh(x)\to\pm\infty$ as $x\to\pm\infty$ so the integral doesn't converge, no complex analysis needed :-).

Comment: @robjohn: Ah, thanks!

Comment: @AleksVlasev $\large\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}{\rm e}^{{\rm i}ax}\,{\rm d}x = 2\pi\,\delta\left(a\right)$ ---> [See this link](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirac_delta_function)

Answer (score 1):

This is the Fourier transform of $\sinh$, which can be broken down as a sum of exponentials. Because the Fourier transform is a linear operator, your integral is a sum of Fourier transforms of exponentials, that is a sum of Lorentzian functions (as it's shown for instance [here](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/FourierTransformExponentialFunction.html)).